# How to create a Pager in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone have an idea of how to create a pager similar to the one in the Hall Of Fame Section of the ASP.NET website?

http://www.asp.net/community/recognition/hall-of-fame

Is it a GridView? Is it a ListView?
How do I create a Pager that is exactly like the one in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do something like that, you might try to bind your data to an `asp:ListView` and then apply [datatables](http://www.datatables.net) on the client side for "smooth" paging.

To do this, you'll need a table with class of "datatable" and you'll also need thead and tbody for datatables, plus some way to select the table with jQuery (like below, the id of the table in the LayoutTemplate is "tblStuff" and I made sure there is no runat="server"). Also, be careful if you created the LayoutTemplate in the design view, because Visual Studio usually will nest one table inside another one.

```
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table id="tblStuff" class="datatable">
        <thead><tr><th>...(Your <th> elements go here)...</tr></thead>
        <tbody><tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr></tbody>
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
```

Now the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tblStuff').dataTable({
        // See the datatables documentation for all the great options possible
    });
});
```

If your data sets are small enough, you can just stuff everything in the ListView once, send it all down to the client and use datatables to page it.  If your data set is too large for that, you can [configure datatables to use Ajax](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html) for getting page data, and set up a web method to serve one page worth of data at a time.

As for achieving the "exact" look of that hall of fame page, I think you could manage that with the proper CSS.